# Same app, one or two Android projects

Tags: android, layout, tablet, smartphone

I have to build an app for both smartphone and tablet.
In two cases, in the tablet version, I am going to use two Fragments.
But in the smartphone version, I'll use a NavigationDrawer.

So my question is, should I make two different projects, or just one and make different classes for tablet and smartphone?

Comment: Since they are differently structured, I'd keep them separate.

Comment: If you just want a different layout for tablet and smartphone, you can go here : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html

Comment: Its better to use a single app. Because you can reuse methods and variables extensively. What you can do is make a check in the launcher activity(if you have a splash screen/login page) and redirect user to a tablet or phone activity. Handle the rest of the app with fragments

Comment: Its better to have a single App

Comment: Thanks to everybody, finally I'm going to build just one app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a single project to do this, but with extensive use of fragments. And i feel that u can use fragments for both phone and tablet, by using multiple activities on a phone and a single activity on the tablet since the larger screen size can accommodate multiple fragments without congestion.

If you are a beginner, slidenerd tutorials are really good to learn about fragments. All the best